# Android - Override DialogFragment method on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, viewpagerindicator

I'm having some problems to use the DialogFragment. My app has to show three different dialogs: one with a number picker, other to create an item and other to edit an item.
I'm using viewpagerindicator in this activity, so the one that creates the item is called in the actionbar (Activity) and the others when I click on a listview item (fragment).

I created one DialogFragment with three instances, one for each  layout, and I can open than without problems. I implemented the Interface on the Activity and in the Fragment too.

**My problem** is how to get the return of my dialog in my fragment, because I made override of "onDialogPositiveClick" in the activity (for the first layout) and in the fragment (for the other two layouts) but it's only being called in the activity.

**My Dialog:**

```
private static int idLayout;
private static Item myItem;

public interface MyDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(SherlockDialogFragment dialog,
            int layout);

    public void onDialogPositiveClick(SherlockDialogFragment dialog,
            int layout, ItemComanda item);

    public void onDialogNegativeClick(SherlockDialogFragment dialog);
}

MyDialogListener bListener;

public static MyDialog newItem(String title) {
    idLayout = R.layout.dialog_item;

    MyDialog fragment = new MyDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public static MyDialog editItem(String title, Item item) {
    idLayout = R.layout.dialog_item;
    myItem = item;

    MyDialog fragment = new MyDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    args.putString("name", item.getNm_item());
    args.putDouble("price", item.getVl_item());
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public static MyDialog newNumberPicker(String title,
        Item item, int max, int min) {
    idLayout = R.layout.dialog_number_picker;
    myItem = item;

    MyDialog fragment = new MyDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    args.putInt("value", item.getQuantity());
    args.putInt("max", max);
    args.putInt("min", min);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        bListener = (MyDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " implement MyDialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View v = inflater.inflate(idLayout, null);

    String title = getArguments().getString("title");

    Dialog myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getSherlockActivity())
            .setTitle(title)
            .setView(v)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            if (myItem == null) {
                                bListener.onDialogPositiveClick(
                                        MyDialog.this, idLayout);
                            } else {
                                bListener.onDialogPositiveClick(
                                        MyDialog.this, idLayout, myItem);
                            }

                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            bListener
                                    .onDialogNegativeClick(MyDialog.this);
                        }
                    }).create();

    switch (idLayout) {
    case R.layout.dialog_number_picker:
        numberPicker(v);
        break;
    case R.layout.dialog_bill_item:
        itemDialog(v);
        myDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        break;
    }

    return myDialog;
}

private void itemDialog(View v) {
    EditText txtName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_name);
    EditText txtPrice = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_price);

    String name = getArguments().getString("name");
    Double price = getArguments().getDouble("price", 0.0);

    txtName.setText(name);
    txtPrice.setText(String.valueOf(price));

    txtName.requestFocus();
}

private void numberPicker(View v) {
    int value = getArguments().getInt("value");
    int max = getArguments().getInt("max");
    int min = getArguments().getInt("min");

    NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    np.setMaxValue(max);
    np.setMinValue(min);
    np.setFocusable(false);
    np.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    np.setValue(value);
}
```

Comment: can you please add the DialogFragment code?

Comment: Dialog added @donfuxx

Comment: hi, can you please put your code in more structured way, not getting which piece of code belongs to what part/class...